# convert arraylist in java to c

Tags: java, c

I have an arrray list in java like this:

```
public List<Integer> Data = Collections.synchronizedList (new ArrayList());
```

I want to convert it to c array.

Comment: `Data.toArray();`
will convert an ArrayList in Java to an Array.
but what do you mean by c array?

Comment: i think he wants to create a thread safe (synchronized) array in C

Answer (score 1):

I'm asuming you're looking to create a thread safe (synchronized) `ArrayList` in C++.

Taken from: [ArrayList::Synchronized Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3azh197k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-3)

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections;
int main()
{

   // Creates and initializes a new ArrayList instance.
   ArrayList^ myAL = gcnew ArrayList;
   myAL->Add( "The" );
   myAL->Add( "quick" );
   myAL->Add( "brown" );
   myAL->Add( "fox" );

   // Creates a synchronized wrapper around the ArrayList.
   ArrayList^ mySyncdAL = ArrayList::Synchronized( myAL );

   // Displays the sychronization status of both ArrayLists.
   String^ szRes = myAL->IsSynchronized ?  (String^)"synchronized" :  "not synchronized";
   Console::WriteLine(  "myAL is {0}.", szRes );
   String^ szSyncRes = mySyncdAL->IsSynchronized ?  (String^)"synchronized" :  "not synchronized";
   Console::WriteLine(  "mySyncdAL is {0}.", szSyncRes );
}
```